# Excel VBA: If Statement on Filtered Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of data that I filter for "yes" in columns C to K, one column at a time. After I have filtered the range, I want to check column 2, row by row, for the letters 'R' or 'C.' If there is a R I add 1 to `R_counter` and likewise for Cs. Unfortunately, I am getting totally wacky numbers for my counters. I suspect that it might have something to do with when I filter the range and tell it to check rows 2 to however many rows are left, it is checking the actual row number and not just moving down a row, if that makes sense. Any ideas?

*Note: If my description doesn't make sense: Basically, I am interested in whether R or C has more of header 1-9.

[image: Here is the format of data I am using]

Here is what I am getting and what I expect to get: 
[image]

```
For z = 3 To LstSpecCol 
        R_counter = 0
        C_counter = 0
        If (WS_Sel.AutoFilterMode And WS_Sel.FilterMode) Or WS_Sel.FilterMode Then
        WS_.ShowAllData
        End If

        WS_Sel.Range(WS_Sel.Cells(1, 1), WS_Sel.Cells(counter + 1, LstCol1)).AutoFilter _
        Field:=z, Criteria1:="Yes"

        With WS_Sel
        Set rngFilter_Yes = Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1), _
        .Columns(z)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        LstRow_Yes = rngFilter_Yes.Cells.Count
        End With

        For t = 2 To LstRow_Yes
           If WS_Sel.Cells(t, 2) = "R" Then
            R_counter = R_counter + 1
           Else
            C_counter = C_counter + 1
           End If
        Next t
    Next z
```

Comment: whats your expected output? can you please post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored the code a bit and tested it to produce the desired result.

Of note is that:

- I loop through each `Cell` in the `FilteredRange` (the way it is written in the question was looping each `Row` from 2 to the end of the filteredrange, which was picking up rows outside the filter.
- I used a `Select Case` to test for `R`, `C` (mostly because I think it's cleaner).
- I used column 2 in the filtered range to test the `R/C ?` column directly.
- I placed the whole thing inside a `With` to help it process faster.

Code:

```
With WS_Sel

    For Z = 3 To LstSpecCol

        R_Counter = 0
        C_Counter = 0

        If (.AutoFilterMode And .FilterMode) Or .FilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If

        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(counter, LstCol1)).AutoFilter Field:=Z, Criteria1:="Yes"

        Set rngFilter_Yes = Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1), .Columns(2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        For Each cel In rngFilter_Yes
            Select Case cel
                Case Is = "R": R_Counter = R_Counter + 1
                Case Is = "C": C_Counter = C_Counter + 1
            End Select
        Next cel

    Next Z

End With
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Does this have to be done in VBA? The problem becomes incredibly easy on the worksheet using the COUNTIFS function.

E.g. for the 'header1' column, you could write `=COUNTIFS(B2:B6,"R",C2:C6,"Yes")` to count all instances where R/C was "R" and header1 was "Yes". The same idea can be generalized to "C" and to the other headers.

If it must be done in VBA, you can use [Application.Evaluate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) to get this same result through code.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that with LstRow wont return the number of rows, only the number of results left after filtering (The rows still remain but are hidden in between)

If you edit LstRow_Yes to acctually be the last row of the table (unfiltered) then you can edit the inner for-loop like this:

```
For t = 2 To LstRow_Yes
    If Not Range("B" & t).EntireRow.Hidden Then
        If WS_Sel.Cells(t, 2) = "R" Then
            R_counter = R_counter + 1
        Else
            C_counter = C_counter + 1
        End If
    End If
Next t
```

This will make sure you only count the visible rows after filtering.

**Another approach** is to use  `=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$5;"R";C$2:C$5;"Yes")` to get the same result without VBA

Comment: Did you try `COUNTIFS` in the cell you want the result? Note that if the results are on Another sheet you'll have to write `=COUNTIFS(NAMEOFSHEET!$B$2:$B$5;"R";NAMEOFSHEET!C$2:C$5;"Yes)`, where you replace NAMEOFSHEET with the acctual name of the sheet. (and keep the ! )